# Динамически изменять содержание текста по мере ввода в input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Мне нужно чтобы по мере ввода текста в инпут у меня изменялся текст “Hello, <введенный текст>!”. Если ничего не введено то выводится “Hello, stranger". Я добавил в input событие onChange и повесил обработчик. Но не могу понять как сделать так чтобы текст изменялся по мере ввода. Подскажите пожайлуста

```
var Input = React.createClass({

    handleNameChange: function (event) {
        this.setState({
            name: event.target.value
        });
    },

    render:function () {
        return (
             <input type="text" onChange={this.handleNameChange}/>
        );
    }// end function
});

var Text = React.createClass({
   render:function () {
       return (
               <h1>Hello, {this.props.name} </h1>
       )
   }// end function
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <div>
        <Input/>
        <Text name="stranger"/>
    </div>,
    document.getElementById("content")
)
```

Comment: повесьте не на change а на keydown

Comment: и не `onKeyDown`, a `onInput` )
**как по мне**, функционирование не поменяется, но так как-то выглядит правильнее

Comment: Нужно вызывать функцию, которая будет перерендоивать компонент, для этого нужно создать state,  можно вытянуть кортежем. const [value, setValue] = useState() ; react  перерендрит компонент в случае вызова useState

Answer (score 0):

1. Ты не создал стейт
2. Не передаешь пропсы в компонент, который должен рендерить “Hello, <введенный текст>!”
3. Используешь старый синтаксис

Вот так может выглядить решение:

```js
const Hello = ({name}) => (
  <div>{name ? `Hello, ${name}!` : 'Hello, stranger!'}</div>
);

class NameForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {value: ''};
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({value: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event) {
    alert('A name was submitted: ' + this.state.value);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={() => this.handleSubmit()}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={this.state.value} onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)} />
        </label>
        <Hello name={this.state.value} />       
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <NameForm />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Наверно ты ничего не понял и это нормально, решение выше это немного переделанный пример из документации https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html